# how can i determine a day name in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server

i want to know the query so that i can get the name of today`s day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select datename(dw,getdate())
```

Comment: Which language (English, French, Klingon etc) does the returned name use?

Comment: If you have Klingon as your database language you'd get that

Comment: @belugabob - it will return in the language of your current connection, as shown by running `select @@language`

Comment: My original comment was slightly tongue-in-cheek. I intended to highlight the fact that the answer wouldn't necessarily be in English. I'll be more specific next time.

Comment: @harper it returns me the day name thats fine but actually i want 1 print sunday 2 print monday and so .... without using case statement . is it possible in sql server functions

Comment: @rahularyansharma - ask a new question describing properly what you want to do

Comment: @harper sir i posted my question please find on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554714/print-day-name-with-day-number-in-sql-server-2005