# How do I name a column as a date value

Tags: sql

the results look like this but wher the column name says 'Today' I want it to be todays date.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what outcome you'd expect? Also, please indicate the database. Is this about Oracle, MySQL, etc?

Comment: [LOOK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332645/how-can-i-determine-a-day-name-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: your columns are increasing day by day?

Comment: @stukselbax I think that is a different thing.

Comment: It's generally not to be recommended - each SQL query should always returns a result set with the same "shape" - where by "shape", we mean it should have the same columns - where those columns are defined by their *name* and their *type*. So whilst you may find a way to do it (probably with some form of dynamic SQL), it would be better to do this kind of formatting trick at another layer - maybe in a reporting tool?

Comment: so you want the date of today as the column name?You want to do it with an SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this technique:

```
declare @dt datetime
declare @sql varchar(100)
set @dt = getdate()
set @sql = 'select 1 as [ ' + convert( varchar(25),@dt,120) + ']'  
exec (@sql)
```

In your Case:

```
declare @dt datetime
declare @sql varchar(100)
set @dt = getdate()
set @sql = 'select 0 as [ ' + convert( varchar(25),@dt,120) + ']'  
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Error raised!exactly because this is wrong way you executing!

Publish your query than i will send back after correction

Comment: This is the very basic of what I want: select 0 as GetDate() so the column name is todays date...

Answer (score 0):

I would return an integer representing a day offset and parse it in the client, failing that you are going to have to use dynamic SQL or do something with the underlying column name itself;;

```
declare @sql nvarchar(128) = '
select 
  col1,
  col2,
  0 as [' + cast(getdate() as nvarchar(32)) + ']
from T'
exec(@sql)
```

Or

```
--today
declare @now varchar(32) = cast(getdate() as varchar(32)) 

--result to temp table
select col1, col2, 0 as [Now] into #T from TheTable
--rename col
exec tempdb..sp_rename '#T.Now', @now, 'COLUMN'
--select
select * from #T
```