# DATENAME as Column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have been reading quite a few SO threads & others on how to achieve this, but nothing is really helping me.

IE:

*[How do I name a column as a date value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691865/how-do-i-name-a-column-as-a-date-value)*

*[current month as column name](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic666243-324-1.aspx)*

*[todays date as a column name to a simple select statement.](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=155198)*

I could go on showing you threads that I have read, but none seem to answer what I want.

Essentially, what I am trying to do in SQL is this:

```
SELECT
    Blahblah AS DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) --AS "September"
```

OR

```
DECLARE
    @CM VARCHAR(50)

SET
    @CM = DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE())

SELECT 
    Blahblah AS @CM --AS "September"
```

I'm aware that none of those work, but that is to show you what I am trying to do. Has anyone been able to achieve this?

Could you point me to a Thread you may have read that helped you do this?

Many thanks,

Mike

Comment: use pivot table, also show some example table

Comment: Hmmm, so its not as simple as I was thinking? I might just give up on this idea :( haha

Comment: sorry.. i thought more.. its simple.. check the answer

Comment: What *are* you asking? The month name is a piece of data, not a name. Do you want to display some statistic by month, pivoted to show the month rows as columns? That's what the [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) operators are for

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe use dynamic sql like this:

```
create table t (val int)
insert t values (100)

declare @month varchar(20) = datename(month, getdate())

declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'select val as ' + @month + ' from t'
exec (@sql)
```

Result:

```
September
-----------
100
```

Answer (score 0):

TRy this

```
DECLARE
@CM VARCHAR(50),
@sql varchar(max)
SET    @CM = DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE())

SET @sql ='SELECT 
''Blahblah'' as '+ @CM
exec(@sql)
```