# MYSQL Date as column headers?

Tags: mysql, date, header, calculated-columns

I'm pretty sure this is really easy and I'm being dumb, so sorry in advance!

I just want columns with dates as the headers.

**EG:**

```
SELECT X, Y, Z, 
SUM(IF(date = curdate() - interval 31 DAY, COUNT(VOLUME), "")) as CURDATE() - interval 31 DAY
```

So pretty much, sum the volume for one day and label the column as the date that's been calculated.

Am I massively off target?

Searching resulted in an attempt of:

```
SET $31 = CURDATE() - interval 31 day;
SELECT data as $31
```

This just produces $31 as the label rather than the value it should pull.

I've typed out probably 30 questions for stack overflow but usually fix them whilst typing. This one however, no joy. Any help appreciated. Merry Christmas.

**Desired:** Col1, Col2, Col3, 23-11-2015, 24-11-2015, 25-11-2015 etc

Comment: SELECT data as \`23-11-2015\`

Comment: @EdGibbs the report would be invalid tomorrow. It needs to be a recurring daily report

Comment: without hard coding or using dynamic SQL I don't think you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691865/how-do-i-name-a-column-as-a-date-value  Most places recommend naming the column something else and converting the column name in the application.  Or maybe... http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31115/giving-a-name-to-a-dynamic-column

Comment: Ah, of course - sorry about that. Reading more carefully (as I should have done in the first place), I'm not sure how you can do that in MySQL.

Comment: @xQbert sadly that Microsoft SQL solution isn't working for me in mysql workbench. That's where I ended up with the "SET" line but yes, perhaps it's a duplicate of an unsolvable question.

Comment: All I can find is using dynamic SQL (here's a mySQL link.)http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this type of result relatively simply with a stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE test_col_name ()
 BEGIN
   SET @stmt := CONCAT("SELECT 1 AS '", CURDATE(), "'");

  PREPARE p_stmt FROM @stmt;
  EXECUTE p_stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE p_stmt;
 END//

mysql> call test_col_name();
+------------+
| 2015-12-23 |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.09 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you - Will give it a try when I'm back at work.

Comment: Ok, marking this as the solution, however I don't appear to have privileges to crease procedures on my work server.