# How do you print the day name given a day number in SQL Server 2005 using SQL commands?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to be able to pass in a day number like 1, 2, 3 or 7 and it will return the day name like Sunday, Monday, Tuesday or Saturday. I know there is the option of using a `case` statement but I would like to do this using SQL commands, would this be at all possible?

```
DECLARE @m VARCHAR
SET @m=1
SELECT CASE WHEN @m=1 THEN 'Sunday' END
```

I have already commented on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332645/how-can-i-determine-a-day-name-in-sql-server-2005) when looking for an answer but user @harper suggested that I should submit a new question with a full description.

**EDIT:**
there is currently answers are given for case statement mostly except one . so again now i am putting my question again here  is

**" I would like to do this using SQL commands, would this be at all possible?"**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
declare @m varchar 
set @m=1 
SELECT DATENAME(DW,CAST(@m AS INT))
```

Comment: @Chaudhari it returns me tuesday and i already mention in my question that i want 1 for sunday

Comment: Returns `martedì` for me? `SET DATEFIRST 4;SET LANGUAGE Italian;declare @m varchar set @m=1 SELECT DATENAME(DW,CAST(@m AS INT))`  (NB: Doesn't really - Just pointing out that result will depend on these settings)

Comment: By default 0=Monday and 1=Tuesday and so on, so you can do one thing. You can substract 2 from passed value and then you will get required result. SELECT DATENAME(DW,CAST(@m AS INT)-2)

Comment: The ordinal values assigned to the days of the week are controlled by the (connection specific) `DATEFIRST` option - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx

Comment: @MartinSmith : If you set datefirst by SET DATEFIRST 4 then also it's not possible to get SELECT DATENAME(DW,1) = 'Sunday'.

Comment: This answer only works by accident and wrong assumptions. `DATENAME` works with dates only, so integers are implicitly cast to datetime. NO, Monday isn't 0 by default. The constant used for Monay in `DATEFIRST` is 1. `1900-01-01` was a Monday though, a lucky coincidence. That's why changing `DATEFIRST` doesn't affedt the result of `SELECT DATENAME(dw,0)` as one would expect. Because that `0` is treated `1900-01-01`, not some date constant

Comment: In fat, `select datename(dw,17)` is perfectly valid, precisely because the integer is converted to a datetime

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server Denali has the [`CHOOSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213019%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx?ocid=aff-n-in-loc--pd) function that will make this more concise. In the meantime just use `CASE` inside the UDF.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.WeekDay(@d int)
RETURNS VARCHAR(9)
WITH SCHEMABINDING, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN
RETURN 
(
SELECT 
    CASE @d
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Saturday'
    END
)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(@dtDate DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @rtDayofWeek VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @rtDayofWeek = CASE DATEPART(weekday,@dtDate)
WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday'
WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday'
WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday'
WHEN 7 THEN 'Saturday'
END
RETURN (@rtDayofWeek)
END
GO

-- Call this function like this:
SELECT dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(GETDATE()) AS DayOfWeek
```

orignally from : [SQL SERVER – UDF – Get the Day of the Week Function](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/23/sql-server-udf-get-the-day-of-the-week-function/)

Comment: `DATEPART(weekday` is dependant on `@@DATEFIRST`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATENAME(DW,CAST(a AS INT))
```

Here we can change the  value of **a** as **0 to 6** 
Default, 0-Monday to 6- Sunday.
If we use **a=7** then it will be calculated as **0**, because 7-7=0.

Comment: Not at all - `DATENAME` works with `datetime` and the integer is implicitly converted to a `datetime`. `cast(0 as datetime)` returns 1900-01-01 which was Monday. The only constant value for Monday is the one used by `SET DATEFIRST`, 1

Comment: Which is why `select datename(dw,17)` also works